# Merge two XML Files in C#

Tags: c#, xml, merge, linq-to-xml

Hello I'm trying to combine two XML files. However, I never get the connection in the right place. I tried two things but without success.

The two XML files look like this:

[image]

[image]

and they should look like this after:

[image]

I tried like
1#

```
var combinedUnique = doc2.Descendants("Actors")
                     .Union(doc1.Descendants("Actors"));
combinedUnique.First().Save(path);
```

But this deletes the Root and every "Actors"..

```
        MyDoc.Root.Add(XDocument.Load(System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.dataPath, "Resources/actors2.xml")).Descendants("Actor"));
        MyDoc.Save(path);
```

And this adds the "Actor" under "Actors".
But i want to merge all "Actor" into "Actors" but how?

Comment: You have to read the XML yourself and add the nodes manually to the corresponding parent node, nobody knows if `Actor` is a child of `actors`

Comment: How do i do that? I thought i could add nodes between the "Actors" Tag

Comment: Can you post your xml content as text, maybe i can give oyu a small demo.

Answer (score 0):

I checked for the linq `.Union()` method. It eliminates all duplicate nodes, thats the answer why you are missing something, you should achieve a proper result in using `Concat()` which preserves duplicate nodes